# How to access elements returned from QSqlquerymodel set query

Tags: sql, qt

I am having trouble understanding how i access the returned elements when i implement a QSqlQueryModel.

I know that you can do
    QSqlQuery query;

```
query.prepare("select * from database");

query.exec();

query.next();

qDebug() << "value in 0 is " << query.value(0).SomeFormat;
```

So i want to do something like that with QSqlQueryModel (apparently the better way to go).. where i set the query, then i can output the values to another lot of boxes i have.
what i have so far is...

```
QSqlQuery selectAllUserFields;

selectAllUserFields.prepare(QString("SELECT * from %1 WHERE %2=:firstName and %3=:lastName;")
                            .arg(dbase::c_userTableName)
                            .arg(dbase::c_colUserFirstName)
                            .arg(dbase::c_colUserSecondName));

// finds the index of the current selection, so we can select the row
QModelIndexList tableIndex = m_ui->populatedUserBox->selectionModel()->selection().indexes();


QString firstName = tableIndex.at(0).data().toString();

QString lastName = tableIndex.at(1).data().toString();

QSqlQueryModel dbUsers;

dbUsers.setQuery(selectAllUserFields);

qDebug() << "DEBUG: {temp} " << dbUsers.record(0).value(0).toString();
```

I am beginnerish, so would appreciate a nudge in the right direction if anyone could assist.

Thanks
Grant

Comment: Maybe you can iterate through model's records from 0 to QSqlQueryModel::rowCount?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you have a look at the QSqlQueryModel documentation "Detailed Description" section where it gives an example. To help you further, here is some code that I wrote for an application to iterate over the model result set:

```
for(int i = 0; i < sqlQueryModel->rowCount(); ++i)
{
    qDebug() << sqlQueryModel->record(i).value(0).toString();
}
```

Another way to do it is to use the function QSqlQueryModel::data(); Again I suggest that you review the documentation here: http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qsqlquerymodel.html